# Also show error message when value is empty during form validation

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

The problem I have is actually even visible in the official SmartGWT demo here: https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_validation_regexp

If you enter nothing (leave field empty) and press validate, no error is displayed. For required value, I need the error shown even when the field is empty.

I set my validator to this:

```
    RegExpValidator regExpValidator = new RegExpValidator();  
    regExpValidator.setExpression("^[0-9A-Z_]{7,12}$");  
    regExpValidator.setErrorMessage("Code must contain capital letters and numbers");
    codeField.setValidators(regExpValidator);
```

Now this expression does NOT match an empty string. Yet, I get no error on validation.

How to show errors for empty required values in forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use setError method. And return the form back.

```
if(codeField.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
codeField.setError("The Code must not be Empty.");
return;
}
```

This will give the form back and also validate the empty string.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that, but it seemed stupid to have to validate the value manually when I have a validator.